# Get unique records based on multi-join with conditionals

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:  `posts`, `users`, `mentions`, `following`

```
posts
----------------------------
id  |  user_id  |  post_text
1      1           foo
2      1           bar
3      2           hello
4      3           jason

users
------------
id  |  name
1      jason
2      nicole
3      frank

mentions
--------------------------
id  |  post_id  |  user_id
1      4           1


following
-------------------------------------------------
id  |  user_id  |  user_id_of_user_being_followed
1      1           2
```

`posts` includes the user_id of the user who posted some text
`users` has the user id and name of the user
`mentions` has the post id and user id of any post which has mentioned 1 or more other users
`following` has a the user id and the user they are following (user can follow 0 to many users)

What I'm trying to do is return all posts from users a that a given user follows, PLUS any posts that have mentioned that user (whether or not the given user is following), without returning any duplicates.

```
SELECT p.id, p.post, u.name, 
FROM following f 
JOIN posts p ON f.following = p.user_id
JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id 
WHERE f.user_id = :user;
```

The above returns all posts from users that a given user is following, but I'm struggling figuring out how to include mentions as well (remember, a user does not have to follow someone to be able to see the post they've been mention in).

UPDATE:
Thanks to John R I was able to figure this out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.id), p.post, u.name 
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN following f ON f.following = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN mentions m ON m.posts_id = p.id 
JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE (f.user_id = :user_id OR m.user_id = :user_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your querstion correctly you would want a left join to include any mentions.. but not filter out any followers/posts

if you can add some **sample data** to play with I can make sure its working how you want it to...

```
SELECT 
    if(p.id is not null, p.id, p1.id) as post_id, 
    if(p.post is not null, p.post, p1.post) as post_text, 
    u.username, m.id, m.user_id
FROM posts p
JOIN users u on u.id = p.user_id
JOIN following f on f.user_id_of_user_being_followed = u.id
LEFT JOIN mentions m on m.user_id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN posts p1 on p1.id = m.post_id
WHERE f.user_id = :user or m.user_id = :user;
```

I left join mentions to the post made and also when the user_id in the mention table is equal to the specified user to filter out other users. the left join shouldn't change the number of rows returned.. but only include any mentions

---

**EDIT:**  [WORKING FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/182fc/1)

after playing around with it I realised it was trying to put all of the data into one row.. try this:

```
(
    SELECT p.id, p.post_text, u.name
    FROM posts p
    JOIN users u on u.id = p.user_id
    JOIN following f on f.user_id_of_user_being_followed = u.id
    WHERE f.user_id = 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT p.id, p.post_text, u.name
    FROM following f
    JOIN mentions m on m.user_id = f.user_id
    JOIN posts p on p.id = m.post_id
    join users u on u.id = p.user_id
    WHERE f.user_id = 1
);
```

Comment: hmm, this doesn't appear to work because we've already limited the posts being returned based on `JOIN posts p ON f.following = p.user_id` - at least I think that's why.

Comment: can you provide a few rows of data for me to work with? i can see where im missing it in theory if you do

Comment: edited the original post.
as you can see, user 1 is only following user 2, however user 3 has mentioned user 1 in post 4. So user 1 should see all posts from user 2, AND the post that they were mentioned in (as defined by the mentions table).

Comment: @kylex I just edited my query.. sql fiddle sometimes gives some weird results so it wasnt showing up exactly right.. but the data is still there... try doing that query..

Comment: I got it, I'm giving you an upvote 'cause you helped get me there. I'll post my solution in an edit in just a minute.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you inherited this db; but the last table is not really in line with good data normalization. The table should be the id and following_id; as set up you'll eventually run out of columns (or have to keep adding them when a user gets an error) - new users won't be able to follow anyone.